# Type error occurred: list indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Im trying to load a json file and loop through the dictionary to get the key values of my choice, after that I will be saving those values in an excel sheet using pandas dataframe. But when I run load the document, I'm getting the error

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

**Below is my entire code in order to achieve that,**

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests

URLs = ['http://httpbin.org/ip',
'http://httpbin.org/user-agent',
'http://httpbin.org/headers']

json_list = []
for url in URLs:
    data = requests.get(url)
    resolvedwo = data.json()
    json_list.append(resolvedwo)

    with open('resolvedworesolution.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(json_list, f, sort_keys=True, indent = 4)
with open('C:\\Users\\resolvedworesolution.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
columns = ['Title', 'Status']
df_ = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for ib in data['documents']:
    tit = ib['title']
    stat = ib['status']
print(tit, stat)
df_ = df_.append(pd.Series([tit, stat], index=df_.columns), ignore_index=True)
df_.to_excel('C:\\Users\\resolved_wo_resolution.xls', index=False)
```

**Note: The URLs mentioned above is for example only. The URL which I am using is the Internal, so I can't share it here. Thus the URL will return the JSON data looks like below.**

**EDITED json:**

```
[
    {
        "documents": [
            {
                "title": [Sample Title 1],
                "status": [true]
            },
            {
                "title": [Sample  Title 2],
                "status": [false]
            }
        ]
    }
]
    [
    {
        "documents": [
            {
                "title": [Sample Title 1],
                "status": [true]
            },
            {
                "title": [Sample  Title 2],
                "status": [false]
            }
        ]
    }
]
    [
    {
        "documents": [
            {
                "title": [Sample Title 1],
                "status": [true]
            },
            {
                "title": [Sample  Title 2],
                "status": [false]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Post complete error message

Comment: @PaulRooney  can you answer your suggestions

Comment: I didn't get a clear picture at wat you are suggesting so, if u post as an answer with more clarity I will get better understanding. That's y

Answer (score 1):

The origin of your issue is here

```
for ib in data['documents']:
```

Your data is a list. So you can't use a string as an index into it.

You have a few options. if you know the list is always one entry (it will break for 0 entries), or if you only care about the first entry

```
for ib in data[0]['documents']:
    # etc...
```

If you want to process all entries use a loop

```
for d in data:
    for ib in d['documents']:
        # etc...
```

When you have errors like this, please post the full traceback error. If we dont have this information we need to run the code ourselves and it takes longer.

e.g.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdcrash4.py", line 21, in <module>
    for ib in data['documents']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: it does return value but it does not runs through all the values in the document file

Comment: for each URL we will have 'documents' list. so when I dump it to a single json file, the FOR loop runs inside only one 'document' dictionary. I want to run loop through all the 'document' available in the json file.

The JSON file will look the same I have updated in the question section above

Comment: perhaps your data isn't what you expect. Try printing it out before running the loop.